# ShowModalDialog of javascript is not closing from ASP Code behind and opening a new pop up of same page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i m opening an Webpage(Clock.aspx) from window.showModalDialog of javascript.In the Clock.aspx i have a button and i want that when the user click on that button the Clock.aspx page will be closed. I dont want to use onClientClick() method of javascript as some server side database insertion is going on and after the insertion i want to close this page.

The Code behind of the button is as follows:-

```
protected void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _nonProduction = new NonProduction();
        if (Session["LastNonProdTimeID"] == null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            int NonProdTimeEntryID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastNonProdTimeID"]);
            //Updating the TimeSpent
            isTimeSpentUpdated = _nonProduction.UpdateTimeSpentInDB(NonProdTimeEntryID);
            if (isTimeSpentUpdated == true)
            {

                string timespent = Convert.ToString(_nonProduction.GetTimeSpent(NonProdTimeEntryID));
                string msg = "Total time consumed  in " +HiddenTaskname.Value.ToString()+": " + timespent.ToString() + " Minutes";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "closePage", "<script type='text/JavaScript'>window.close();</script>");

                //ShowPopUpMsg(msg);
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }



    }
```

Here when i m clicking on the Button one more (Clock.aspx)pop up is appearing and window is not closing. Please help me that how i close the ShowModalDialog from server side code. I m using Script manager in my page also.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added `<base target="_self">`to the head section of the clock.aspx page and then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For mine, I have a function in normal javascript that closes the page in the aspx.

In the code behind, if the update is successful, it calls that function.

```
// this function is to be called by the popup windows to refresh the opener using specific office code, and close self
function allDoneOffice(office)
{
    var opener = self.opener;
    if (opener.doRefresh) opener.doRefreshWithOfficeCode(office);
    window.open('','_self','');  // IE warning hack
    self.close();
}


        // update the record
    bool b = report.SaveModifiedToDB();
    if (b)
    {
        // don't close the page if nothing was updated
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
        "allDoneOffice('" + report.OfficeCode + "');" + "<" + "/script>");
    }
    else
    {
        lblResults.Text += " Unable to save modified report to the database.";
    }
```

Comment: Implemented the code as per you but still getting the same problem, when i m clicking on the button it is opening a new pop up of clock.aspx page but the window is not closing.I had also changed the function like your code and then call in my code but once i m clicking a new pop up of Clock.aspx is coming but now closing the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code below should work in IE

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { self.close() }</script>");
```

Comment: Implemented the code as per you but still getting the same problem, when i m clicking on the button it is opening a new pop up of clock.aspx page but the window is not closing.